# How to load react-native(Android) a bundle remotely

Tags: android, react-native

I created an android module in my APP with react-native Android, In my case, I am trying to load a JS bundle file remotely, but it's always loading from localhost, and I see the config to bundle's location is hard coded in `DevServerHelper.java`, the bundle file in my APP's assets folder is read-only when APP running so I can't modify it dynamically.

so can I load the bundle file remotely? If not, how can I implementation an upgrade feature in APP use react-native?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Any updates on this @misaku please help because I am also looking for same

Answer (score 0):

You can load the bundle remotely by changing the `Debug server host for device` setting under `Dev Settings` in the rage shake menu. It is also explained in the react native docs about [how to run on device](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content).