# React Native Production - Fetch JS from remote server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How to configure the React native library in android to fetch the JS bundle from a remote server. 
While developing I know it fetches from a local server. 
How to set the remote url where the react native library can fetch the JS bundle from. I dont want to package the JS code inside the app build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649256/can-react-nativeandroid-load-a-bundle-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reccomend that approach since apple started to rejecting apps built like this. If you don't mind or targeting android only I would suggest looking at [codepush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/)